# Finding number of different sorted triplets where each item is from a different set

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

While doing some leisure coding, I've come accross the following problem: consider three sets of integers. How many different triplets can be made so that:

- All three numbers in the triplet are from different sets;
- Two triplets are considered to be equal if they are equal when the elements are sorted (for example, (1, 2, 3) and (2, 3, 1) are considered to be equal).

Let's take an example. Let's say the three sets are {1, 2}, {1, 3} and {1, 2, 3}. The answer should be 8 and the actual triplets would be 111, 112, 113, 123, 133, 122, 223, 233.

What is the most efficient algorithm for finding this number (note that I only need the total number of such triplets, not the triplets themselves)? Also it would be interesting to know, if the algorithm can be generalized to N sets of numbers and tuples of length N.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what triplet is?

Comment: I think he means that he wants to create *arbitrary* triplets. A triplet has three slots. The first slot is a number drawn from the first set. The second slot is drawn from the second set, ... Under all possible triplets that can be generated he wants to find out how many of them are equal (ignoring order).

Comment: @YonggooNoh: A set of three elements.

Comment: I think you can get the solution easier at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the example? I'm not sure why `111` and `112`, etc., are considered equal. Or why you list exactly those `8` triplets.

Comment: Another way to look at this is by considering the product (a + b)(a + c)(a + b + c) = a^3 + 2a^b + 2a^2c + ab^2 + 3abc + ac^2 + b^2c + bc^2. There are 8 distinct terms and the coefficient is the number of times the term (or triplet) is repeated.

Comment: @Zabuza OP is looking for the number of distinct (i.e. non-equal) triplets. None of the 8 triplets in the example are considered equal. An example of equal triplets would be 112 and 211.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough with my description. Dukeling and AlexP got it right :) A triplet is a collection of three numbers, e.g. (1,5,12) is a triplet. The first element doesn't necessarily have to be from the first set, the main rule is that all three elements must be from different sets.

Comment: Not elaborated but probably an useful approach: Assume all numbers would be distinct. How many combinations are there (how many triplets in total)? You can very easily compute this. Then, process each number of each set (only `7` in your example). For each number compute how many triplets do contain it. Merge the number for `1` of the first set with `1` of the second and third set. Then you know in how many triplets a `1` is part of in the end etc.